# たまにSSL_connectエラー？が出現する

Tags: ruby

題名の通りrubyでプログラムを実行すると普段は問題なく動作するのですが、たまに以下のようなエラーが出力して動作が止まってしまいます。

```
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock': An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect(Errno::ECONNRESET)

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock': An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
```

自分でも調べてみたのですが答えを見つけれず…
普段は正常に動作しているので何が原因なのか初心者の私ではよく分かりません。
おそらく私の知識不足でしょうが、解決方法を教えて頂きたいです。

必要ないかもしれませんが以下の`case s.connect_nonblock(exception: false)`がprotocol.rbの44の部分です。

```
    def ssl_socket_connect(s, timeout)
      if timeout
        while true
          raise Net::OpenTimeout if timeout <= 0
          start = Process.clock_gettime Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC
          # to_io is required because SSLSocket doesn't have wait_readable yet
          case s.connect_nonblock(exception: false)
          when :wait_readable; s.to_io.wait_readable(timeout)
          when :wait_writable; s.to_io.wait_writable(timeout)
          else; break
          end
          timeout -= Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC) - start
        end
      else
        s.connect
      end
    end
  end
```

OSはwindows10です。

Comment: 接続先を変えても同様のエラーは発生しますか？

Answer (score 1):

SSLのバージョンは適切でしょうか？

例えばサーバー側はTLS v1.2しか受け付けないのに、クライアント側がSSL V3.0〜TLS v1.0で接続した場合など、本来、エラーが返されるべきですが、サーバーに依ってはいきなり切断するものもあります。